# SSIS Log error message for specific CSV files when importing

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Using MS SSIS within SQL Server 2016.  I have a loop that reads multiple .txt files from a directory, assigns the filename to a variable (strFileName) and also loads the contents of each .txt file into a table.

Within the loop I also have an Execute SQL Task that uses the strFileName variable as a Parameter and inserts the filename of the CSV into a logging table so I can see exactly what was loaded.

Is there anyway I can expand the Execute SQL Task to also insert the System Error Description - if and when the occur?  The system error message does not appear in the drop down on the parameter mapping of the Execute SQL Task.

I understand there is Loggint etc at package level, but what I really want is the file name of the .txt file and a column with any error messages in.

Is this actually possible?

Thanks for all help\advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use the On_error Event Handler to get the System::Error Variable.

You can put your Execute SQL into here or set some variables & use them afterwards.

Rgds

Comment: I have followed your advice and it is working for me - thank you.